# How to prevent Drupal export XML formatter adding paragraphs?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I'm exporting nodes as XML and with fields in most nodes set to "Plain text" format. Everything is fine when I'm editing them, but when exporting an extra paragraph (`<p>`) tag is added around text (using "Default" formatter).

The mentioned field has a variable length text (some are short like "Book" and some have long HTML). Some longer texts are exported fine, but those short ones all have extra paragraph around them (e.g. `<p>Book</p>`).

So is there some option I can check to disable adding those paragraphs or even disable any formatting? Or maybe I have to install/make some special module for formatting?

PS: I'm using [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) (version 7.x-3.0-beta8).

Comment: And your view is outputting full nodes, or fields?

Comment: I'm also curious if you tried the XML output from views_datasource - though Views data export claims to handle larger amounts of data so ymmv.

Comment: Full nodes, no. Only some choosen fields, but all of a single contet type. I haven't tried other modules as VDE seems more appropriate for my needs - large data set (more then 2K) and I will need to filter results later (e.g. by date of last update).

Comment: So I see this when the default format is selected, but not if I choose 'plain text'. I'm guessing plain text doesn't work for you for another reason, but the important thing is that these format options aren't specific to thew views XML data export module, they are configured elsewhere in Drupal. I was able to get rid of the <p> tag by disabling 'Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)' for the input format used on the field. Which is not ideal, so you may need to install or create a different field formatter, possibly https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_text_formatter

Comment: Good point! I had to disable changing new lines to HTML new lines and it worked. Not ideal, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need to ***make*** a "special module". Instead you could ***install*** the [Forena](http://drupal.org/project/forena) module (with quite a few official D7 releases ...), as an alternative to what you're trying to do with the [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module (or the [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module as suggested in one of the comments to the question here).

You could use the [Forena](http://drupal.org/project/forena) module to create an appropriate report. As per your comment like "*Full nodes, no. Only some choosen fields, but all of a single content type.*" such report should be straight forward to create. And then create an XML file from the report data (= query results). Similar solution for somebody who rather wants/needs a JSON format. Refer to my answer to "[How to add a link to the CSV download to my module page, for a report created with Forena?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165554)" for more details about all sorts of export formats, and some online demo samples.

Using this alternative, you probably don't need your (*not ideal*) work-around anymore which is to *disable changing new lines to HTML new lines*.