# How to add a link to the CSV download to my module page, for a report created with Forena?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, log-messages, forena

How do I add a link to the CSV download created by the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module to my module page?

Do I just copy the link in 'inspect element' and put that in my `$output` variable that I return on the recommendations page?

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165512/reportwriting-questions-about-the-forena-reports-module for the background of this question.

Comment: This question was 1 out of 3 questions contained in the **original version** of the question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165512 (refer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/165512/1 for more details).

Comment: I keep wondering why this question was converted (by a moderator) to a wiki question (and hence answer also) ... Hope some day an undo of that will happen ... Or that somebody will provide me a "good" reason (that make sense to me) for doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any report that you create (using [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena)), just add `.csv` as an extention to the report (output) URL. That contains the CSV equivalent of that report.

As a sample, consider the sample report located at `/reports/sample.states` (in your own site, one of the samples shipped with Forena). Change the URL to `/reports/sample.states.csv` (= just add `.csv` to it) to get the same report in `.csv` format.

If you'd adding such `.csv` to the URL of the [Simple Table of States in the demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states), the result is [like so](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.csv) ...

Same technique applies for other supported extensions (export formats), such as adding `.html`, `.xls` (MS Excell), `.pdf` or `.doc` (MS Word).

By the way, all *data blocks* are accessible directly via their url also, provided you have permission to access that block. Here are a few samples of that, for the sample report located at `/reports/sample.states`:

- in [XML format](http://forenasolutions.org/forena/xml/sampledb.states) (= demo **with** anonymous access).
- in [JSON format](http://forenasolutions.org/forena/json/sampledb.states) (= demo **with** anonymous access).
- in [XML format](http://drupal.placeto.be/forena/xml/sampledb.states) (= demo **without** anonymous access).
- in [JSON format](http://drupal.placeto.be/forena/json/sampledb.states) (= demo **without** anonymous access).